# how do I add a 'groups' custom claim to id_token issued by Cognito?

Tags: spring-security, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

I want to use a custom claim on an open id connect id_token to indicate the groups that the user belongs to.

I have this working with Okta and Spring Security 5. With Okta there was a simple way to set-up a custom claim and associate it with a user's groups.

Now I want to do the same with Cognito.

How do I use Spring Securities group/role authorities in conjunction with Cognito?

I have open id connect login working with Spring Security 5, Webflux & Cognito but now I want to add some role based, group membership coarse-grained entitlements.

I have added a custom attribute to my user-pool but can't see how to populate it.

thanks

Comment: I'm exploring a custom attribute that could be populated via a [pre-token-generation-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html)

Comment: have come back into the office after a long weekend to discover that there is now a `cognito:groups` claim on the id_token populated with the user's groups. Now I'm wondering how its decided to appear! I didn't have the permissions to create the lambda, so from my perspective I don't think I did anything other than add a new custom attribute called `groups` to the user pool. Though that wasn't working when I left the office.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add an implementation example here.

I use my custom **JwtAuthenticationConverter** to extract cognito:groups and bind them to Spring Security Authorities.

Stack is the same as yours (Webflux, Spring 5 [boot]). Here is the converter class:

```
@Component
public class GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor extends JwtAuthenticationConverter {

    @Override
    protected Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Jwt jwt) {
        val authorities = (Collection<String>) jwt.getClaims().get("cognito:groups");

        if (authorities == null) {
            return emptyList();
        }

        return authorities.stream()
                          .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                          .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

And here is the related part in my SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                        GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor extractor) {
    http
        // ...
        // Other configurations
        // ...
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(extractor));

    return http.build();
}
```

Also one point that should be mentioned is that **@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity** annotation should be placed above SecurityConfiguration class to enable functionality of @PreAuthorize annotations across the application.

Comment: Hi Zahid, I am not working on this project anymore (as well as with reactive and AWS stack). And I don't remember the details unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have created another user pool and confirm that adding a custom attribute to the Cognito user pool with the name of 'groups', that is mutable, has resulted in the id_token returned from an openid scope call having a `cognito:groups` custom claim containing strings representing the groups that the user is allocated to.  If the user isn't allocated to any groups then the claim doesn't appear on the token. I suspect this is why I believed it to not be initially working. I couldn't find any explicit documentation that said this his how it works thought.  Hope this helps someone, cheers.

Comment: regarding Spring security, the peice of code I wrote to extract a custom claim and update the `GrantedAuthorities` of the user - I made the name of the custom claim configurable as that varied between Okta and Cognito for me.